# Play Framework 2.1 : Performance issue with play.libs.WS

Tags: performance, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have a Play 2.1 Java webservice, that calls another webservice.
My service serves JSON made with transforming the XML response of the other webservice.

Initially , I was using a Jersey-Client lib to call my second service.
As this is a blocking call, I've modified the setting to allow 500 threads in parrallel.
I had good results with it , I made a gatling test and it was quite fast (32 seconds to handle 10 000 requests on a distant server).

Then I'ved decided to use only asynchronous calls to optimize the I/O. 
Now I use play.libs.WS client instead of the jersey blocking client with the default thread pool parameters.
I use promises to get my results but the rest of my code is exactly the same as before.

Strangely, the performances with my gatling test (just a loop that sends some http GET requests) has dropped and is more than 10x slower...

I've tried to increase the number of threads for the "default-dispatcher" but it's not better.

Could it be because a single thread processes the XML and Json transformations after the WS call ?

The app is structured as following :

```
//controller : 
Promise<Response> = myService.remoteEntities();

return async(promise.map(new Function<Response, Result>() {
        public Result apply(Response response) {
          List<Entity> entities = // ... XPATH and DOM parsing
          return ok(jsonp(callback, toJson(entities)));
        }      
});
```

myService.remoteEntities is defined like that :

```
public Promise<List<Entity>> myServiceMethod {
 return WS.url(url.toString()) 
}
```

Note : myService is a spring service singleton, and my routes/controllers use spring  with the '@'notation
I 've put this in a separated class to be able to use mocks for my tests

Thanks,
Loïc

Note: I've initially posted my problem here : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/SDpPA6UPyFQ